# Want to show day and month according to selected date

Tags: android, date

```
  calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            if (isStartSelection) {
                String firstdate=String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                String dayofstartweek=(String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEE",Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                String firstmonth=(String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM",month);
                tvSelectedFirstDate.setText(firstdate);
                tvSelectedFirstMonth.setText(firstmonth);
                tvSelectedFirstDay.setText(dayofstartweek);
            } else {
                String enddate=String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                String dayofendweek=(String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEE",Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                String endmonth=(String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM",month);
                tvSelectedEndDate.setText(enddate);
                tvSelectedEndDay.setText(dayofendweek);
                tvSelectedEndMonth.setText(endmonth);
            }

        }


    });
```

Here I am getting correct date,but Day is not changing and month is showing as Jan(for every month it is showing as Jan)

Comment: The second argument in the `format()` method needs to be a `Calendar` object, a `Date` object, or a `long` representing the current time in milliseconds. You're passing a `Calendar` class constant, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
String firstdate=String.valueOf(17);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
String dayofstartweek= new SimpleDateFormat("EEE").format(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
String firstmonth= new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

I have checked, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For more format related you check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). I give comment for other month format related.

```
int dayOfMonth = 20;
        int month = 1;
        int year = 2015;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");

        //You can give different code in SimpleDateFormat for month
        // = new SimpleDateFormat("MM")
        //or = new SimpleDateFormat("M")
        String strMonth = format.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
        Log.e("Month", strMonth);
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        String strdate = format.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
        Log.e("Date", strdate);

        format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        String strYear = format.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
        Log.e("Year", strYear);
```